# Can I limit a process's access to specified files and stdout only without root?

Tags: compiling, c, access-control, jails

I want to setup a server for students to upload C code. The server compiles C code, run the binary and shows output to students.

Now I am having security concern. Students can upload any code, but I want them can access 2 specified files (1 for read and 1 for write with `fopen`) and stdout only. I don't want them to access Internet or any other files on the system.

The server I have is containerized Linux, and I don't have root.

I have thought about these solutions:

1. `chroot` or  `firejail`. (I don't have server's root. It's containerized, setting euid is not allowed)
2. use some `gcc` options, or `.h` files or C library limit. (I have little knowledge about compiling. Theorially people can do  anything with C not using any header files or library)
3. use something like `strace` or `ptrace` to monitor the process and terminate it if it want to do what I don't want it to.

Is it possible to do that?